# Very Specific Multiple Condition Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Struggling a little with two multi conditional formula issues at the moment:

The first is I have a number of dates in Column B of a sheet (that represent the date something was created) and I am trying to make a formula that will allow me to have all the dates that are 90 days to 179 days old (from the date they were created) shade yellow and all the dates that are 180 days old and above shade red. I also need all dates that meet neither of those conditions (0 to 89 days old) to stay normal. This would obviously use the TODAY feature to constantly update based on the date.

The second issue is in Column N I need to show the date in column B plus 90 days, but if there is no information in column B, I need it to show nothing. I can make this work with a very simple N = b2+90 but that obviously means the cell will contain '90' if no date is yet applied in b2.

Any help would be appreciated, I can generally make one of these conditions work but not all at the same time. I have trawled the web for answers but making a formula to meet all those conditions is proving difficult.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the second issue, use an IF statement

```
=if(B2>0,B2+90,"")
```

For the first issue, start by building the logic into worksheet cells temporarily, then combine them with OR() or AND() functions and once you have them working, get them into a Conditional Formatting formula.

A progression of helper formulas would be like the following, who each return either a true or a false.

```
=TODAY()-B2>=90
=TODAY()-B2<180
=and(TODAY()-B2>=90,TODAY()-B2<180)
```

The last one above is the formula needed for the yellow rule.

And the red rule should be fairly obvious

```
=and(B2>0,TODAY()-B2>=180)
```

Apply these two rules to cell B2 and copy the format down with the format painter or in the "apdpdlies to" section of the Rule Manager.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If that helped, please finish the paperwork and accept the answer as described in the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

In N2,

```
=if(count(b2), b2+90, text(,))
```

Create two conditional formatting rules based on these formulas,

```
=and(today()-b2>89, today()-b2<180)   <~~yellow
=and(count(b2), today()-b2>=180)      <~~red
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

Setup two conditions, the first one, to colour the cells yellow should have the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I13),0,DAYS(TODAY(),I13))>89
```

And the second one, to colour them red should have:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I13),0,DAYS(TODAY(),I13))>179
```

Answering your second question:

```
=IF(B2="","",B2+90)
```

*Formulas edited so result isn't true if cells are blank

Comment: Both your cfr formulas are true is B is blank.